# Incorrect Casting

Tags: java, casting

For some reason I am getting a precision error when I try to compile my code. The precision error comes in the return of my second method where I am trying to calculate the circumference. What am I doing incorrectly?

```
public class Methods2
{
   public static final double PI = 3.14;
   public static double calcCirc(double x)
   {
      return PI*x;
   }
   public static int calcCirc(int x)
   {
      return (2*(double) x)*PI;
   }
   public static void main(String[]args)
   {
      System.out.println(calcCirc(10.2));
      System.out.println(calcCirc(4));
   }
}
```

Comment: What is the error? What did you get and what did you expect to get?

Comment: Also, `Math.PI` exists.

Comment: Either calcCirc should be double instead of int OR the return should be casted to int.

Comment: Math.PI not only exists, it is a much better than 3 digit approximation to pi.

Comment: Also: Consider namning your methods `calcCircFromDiameter` and `calcCircFromRadius`. And use double instead of int as both parameter type and return value.

Comment: In the second method, you don't need either the cast or the parentheses. Though if you *really* want to return an int (which you shouldn't) you'll need an `(int)` cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both versions of `calcCirc()` ought to return doubles.

Also, side note--consider using different method names since they accept inputs that differ not only in type but also in semantics.

E.g. `calcCircFromRadius(double radius)`, `calcCircFromDiameter(double diameter)`. There's not really a reason to take an `int` as an input type here since Java will automatically cast `int`s to `double`s for you.

Answer (score 3):

You are attempting to return a `double` value in a method declared to return an `int`.  Java won't let you implicitly narrow your value like that.

If you're okay with the loss of precision, then explicitly cast the value to `int` -- Java will let you do that.

```
return (int) ((2*(double) x)*PI);
```

However, I would change the method to return `double` instead, not to lose precision:

```
public static double calcCirc(int x)
```

... as you already did with your other `calcCirc` method.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
public static int calcCirc(int x){
    return (int)((2*x)*PI);
}
```